# ruby on rails assets storage issue on heroku

Tags: heroku, assets

I have a ruby on rails app,but since quite a long time i am facing an issue.So basically the app is a blog and i have images associated with every post.Now for uploading images i have used the paperclip gem which creates a system folder inside public directory and stores every image associated with the particular blog post with a unique id.

Now when i deployed the app on heroku,it doesnt retain my images,i have to every time upload it again and again.

So please provide some solutions to it.

P.S i dont want to go for a paid web-hosting

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can upload assets on Heroku they will only exist on the dyno that they were uploaded to and will not persist across redeploys or restarts of the dyno (which occurs daily). You need to use an external provider to store your assets, such as Amazon S3, Rackspace Files etc.

Heroku provide detailed documentation on this at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: in my case,when i turn off my pc,the images are lost and when i restart and visit my website,i can no longer c dem,so that means that they are not restartin the dyno daily,but instead,its restarted i guess every time i turn off my pc,and about using cloud storage,the problem with amazon s3 is that they ask for credit card details,which i dont want to provide

Comment: i tried using sumthing called as cloudinary,but unable to use it properly,it gives me an error sayin that the cloud name and id is required inorder to store my images,and i am not able to undertsnd where to provide that cloud name in the cloudinary image upload tag